# Is it a good practice to publicly document an open API?

Tags: rest, http, security

Everybody can be sure of the benefits and the drawbacks of an open API.

But is it a good or a bad practice to publicly document the open API (which requires authentication for its requests)?

By publicly document I mean creating a documentation showing the structure of the body of the request that the API can receive and by giving descriptions for all these fields.

E.g., given an endpoint `my-public.url/myendpoint/myresource`, with available `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` and `GET` http requests there's a static page `my-public.url/document/myendpoint`which shows all the acceptable http requests along with description for the headers and the body of the request that are needed in order to perform it.

On the one side, this will help external developers to use the API easily, but on the other hand, if somebody gains access somehow, it would be easy for them to make requests and corrupt the system, since the whole structure of the API is given.

Comment: What about api keys, tokens etc?

Comment: These should for sure be secret and communicated between the parties that are using and housing the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Risk in your application's APIs is **not at all** increased because of publicly documenting it.

Here are some reasons which I get in mind when thinking of this,

- If you are having a browser based client, anyone with a bit of knowledge to inspect the browser developer tools' **NETWORK** tab can find your API details.
- In case if there is any mobile client which uses your API, the request information can be easily viewed using applications like [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/). The most famous API tester application [POSTMAN](http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/06/26/using-postman-proxy-to-capture-and-inspect-api-calls-from-ios-or-android-devices/) also supports such a functionality.

With the help of the above tools, it's more likely for anyone can know about your API details.

Advantages of public documentation

- API consumers can just visit your public API documentation which clearly saves a lot of man-time in API developer-consumer communication. (Version based API (and documentation) will be very helpful in time of changes in existing ones)
- Creating API demo/test kits like [Postman Collections](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/creating_collections/) will help the API consumers to test and use the APIs easily.

Here are some points which you can note to reduce the risks in your application.

- *Authentication* - Login credentials / Access token / API Keys
- *Authorization* - Access check for any resource which is being accessed / modified.
- *API Rate limiting* - To avoid a DOS attack.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong and in contrast with known security best practice. While there are of course advantages of public documentation, that is indeed a risk as described in my answer below. It doesn't mean that public documentation is wrong, not at all, but it definitely *is* a risk which people have to consider and manage.

Comment: IMO, protecting your APIs is a must to do and with that perspective I answered this question. Also the question says that the api requires proper authentication which implies the developer is trying to address the risk factors. So it’s better to avoid a trade off to risk your application just by avoiding documentation. Handling Security is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this from the risk perspective. Providing public documentation for an API presents a risk, for the reason you mentioned, it may help an attacker. On the other hand, security is always a balance, providing documentation helps (or is even necessary for) your users.

Also you shouldn't implement security by obscurity, ie. how things work should be considered known to attackers - but it's true that many times that's not the case in reality.

As providing public documentation is a risk, you then have to treat it somehow. You can do several things with risk, for example you can accept it (~do nothing), eliminate it (~not provide documentation in this case), or mitigate it.

Mitigating this risk would mean additional things you do to make an exploit less likely, or to decrease the impact. Likelihood can be reduced by for example stronger controls around how you develop your software, adding automated testing around authentication and authorization features, adding static code analyzers to the mix and so on. Impact can be reduced by good architecture that separates logical layers, intrusion detection/prevention systems, or even going for single tenant instead of multi-tenant.

In the end it all comes down to what risk you want to accept, and that entirely depends on you. With proper controls, it is ok to provide public docs - how else could you expect users to be able to use your api? The question is what are "proper" controls, and that depends on your risk appetite.